# Rename pandas columns with datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with unhelpful column names that I'd like to turn into datetimes. The current column names are

```
Index([Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median, Market Median], dtype=object)
```

I've tried to turn them into datetime names with

```
cols = pd.date_range(start='2004-02-28', end='2013-05-31', freq='Q-NOV')
df.columns = cols
```

but I get the error

```
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

`cols` appears to be a valid index:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2004-02-29 00:00:00, ..., 2013-05-31 00:00:00]
Length: 38, Freq: Q-NOV, Timezone: None
```

so I'm not sure of the problem. I also didn't think that columns needed to be named with unique objects so there's probably a more fundamental problem with what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I didn't think they did either, I think someone else also had this issue yesterday...

Comment: posted as an [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3687).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A roundabout way is to [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) of the [transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 2), columns=['A', 'A'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
          A         A
0  0.210915  1.698726
1 -1.423380 -0.861011
2 -0.895981  0.192910

In [3]: df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
          0         1
0  0.210915  1.698726
1 -1.423380 -0.861011
2 -0.895981  0.192910
```

That way you have a uniquely valued Index, and can change the column as you suggest.
*This feels like a workaround...*

Comment: Ah, so the problem is that the original names aren't a uniquely valued index and need to be reset. Great, that workaround sorted things out, thanks.

Comment: @rauparaha yeah, columns are of Index (or MultiIndex) type, little confusing I guess! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug (as noted by @Andy Hayden), and is fixed in the upcoming 0.11.1 (out very soon)

```
In [11]: df = DataFrame([[1,1,1,5],[1,1,2,5],[2,1,3,5]],columns=['a','a','a','a'])

In [12]: idx = date_range('20130101',periods=4,freq='Q-NOV')

In [13]: df = DataFrame([[1,1,1,5],[1,1,2,5],[2,1,3,5]],columns=['a','a','a','a'])

In [14]: df.columns = idx

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
   2013-02-28  2013-05-31  2013-08-31  2013-11-30
0           1           1           1           5
1           1           1           2           5
2           2           1           3           5
```

Comment: my change is not fully merged yet :)

Comment: actually I started this change a few days ago from another question you answered (but I don't remember which one...)